# slapd unment dependency in debian 8

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, slapd

I want to install openLdap package from jessie repository. this is my sources.list file content :

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
```

I run *apt-get update* and get this result :

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources [341 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources [1,439 B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [758 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages [2,506 B]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en [1,211 B]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en [387 kB]
Fetched 1,537 kB in 3s (402 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

then i try to install slapd using *apt-get install slapd* and i get this output :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 slapd : Depends: libltdl7 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not installable
         Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i think this repository has broken slapd. which repository installs slapd without problem ? 
The operating system is Debian 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Add ftp.br.debian.org repo to /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian stable main

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
```